# Access VBA: Is it possible to execute VBA code when the Access DB opens?

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, vba

I have 2 forms I'd like to open when the Database opens based on a condition.

Basically 
If 'table1' exists in the database, then open form1 
Else open form2

Is there a way to get this functionality right when the database first opens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the AutoExec macro and "run form". Create a macro called "AutoExec". Do what is needed in the macro.

There is also a "Display Form" under the "Application Options" that you can use.

Comment: There is no "run form", but there is "open form" but that only lets me open one form unconditionally.

Comment: I tried doing "run code" on a function in a module that opens the right form based on a condition, but when I start my databse, i get the error "The expression you entered has a function name that Access can't find"

Comment: Nevermind figured it out! For anyone interested: the function name cant be the same as the module name.